# How to prevent ObjectDisposedException on an externally provided resource?

Tags: c#, task, dispose, objectdisposedexception

I've got the following task which will run occasionally and utilize externally provided resources.

```
// start receiving the data
receiving = Task.Run(() =>
{
    string dataCopy = string.Empty;
    string next = string.Empty;

    while (true)
    {
        next = this.buffer.Take(t);

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(next))
        {
            // keep appending the data
            dataCopy += next;

            // check if we've gotten the EOL
            if(dataCopy.Contains(endOfLine))
            {
                // remove the EOL
                dataCopy = this.lib.RemoveString(dataCopy, endOfLine);
                break;
            }
        }

        t.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    return dataCopy;
}, t);
```

My intent here is to have the task cancel immediately when another thread pulls the trigger on the `CancellationTokenSource`. Which, seeing as the task spends most of its time sitting on `buffer` (which is of type `BlockingCollection`) the task will *most likely* cancel immediately when `.Take` throws its exception.

Now here is my concern... on the off-chance that the task is executing somewhere between the `.Take` method call but *before* the `this.lib.RemoveString` call... The `lib` object is an externally provided resource and as such will be disposed of *externally* (hopefully after this thread is done executing).

What's to say that my code won't one day throw an `ObjectDisposedException` on trying to call the `RemoveString` method? How can I safeguard against that scenario?

Comment: You can't. Even if  there is a `lib.IsDisposed` , its use wouldn't be thread-safe.

Comment: _"hopefully after this thread ..."_  should be made certain.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How is that possible? What if it's canceled because I am in the process of exiting the program, my next step is to dispose... What if I get ODE?

Comment: When you Cancel, for whatever reason, you'll have to do `receiving.Wait()` before disposing its resources.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was thinking about that, but won't `receiving.Wait()` immediately throw an exception, completely ignoring whether the task is actually finished?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've ran that code, and know it does that but I guess what I am trying to ask is... Will the code actually be done executing inside of the task by the time that the `Wait` method throws its exception?

Comment: Yes, the Wait() will block until the task completes. In your case it will re-throw the CancelException.

Comment: But all in all, I would rather try to provision and keep that lib thing inside the Task. Disposing across threads isn't a great idea.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I would like to, but it's constructor injected and I don't have the `ILibInterface` actually implementing `IDisposable`... thoughts?

Comment: @HenkHolterman What if it's constructor injected without the `IDisposable` interface... as is my case?